# load key : permission denied jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to run a multibranch job in jenkins . Codes are placed in git. While running the job I am getting access rights issue. While generating the `ssh-keygen` in jenkins getting the permission denied error.

Configuring in ubuntu box.

1. Tried copying the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from /root/.ssh but its doesnt copy anything in id_rsa or allow to edit the file manually.

```
 git ls-remote -h git@github.com:****/*****1.git HEAD
The authenticity of host 'github.com ("IP Address")' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:********************Y8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts).
Load key "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: please fix formatting (add 4 spaces to format as code)

Comment: Did you install that `id_rsa.pub` key in your GitHub account?

Comment: Actually, the third line from the bottom suggests you don't have read permission on `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa`. Check if you can read that file first, and adjust the permissions if necessary.

Comment: Thanks all. Issue is now resolved. I had to delete the .ssh directory. Created the .ssh dir and generated the keys again and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

This error is coming because you might have copied the id_rsa file into the location `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/`. You might have copied the file either from local machine to the remote server or created the keys at root level so file "id_rsa" has owner as root and you are trying to access this file from your jenkins. Jenkins should be the owner to read the file.
Below are the steps to check and fix this issue

1. SSH into jenkins server and first run command `sudo su` and then
   go inside `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/`.
2. Run command `ls -la`
3. you will see owner as root root of id_rsa file like `-r--------.  1 root root 18 Sep  1 10:00 id_rsa`
4. Run command `chown jenkins:jenkins id_rsa`. This command will change owner of the file from root to jenkins. Now the same line looks like `-r--------.  1 jenkins jenkins 18 Sep  1 10:01 id_rsa`
5. Now trying running the jenkins job again, it will successfully run.
6. Make sure your id_rsa file should have right permissions. If not for safer side do `chmod 400 id_rsa`

I have solved the issue by following above steps.

Answer (score 0):

`Load key "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied` is about reading the local private ssh key on your local file system, and has nothing to do with the remote server.

Make sure that you have read permission for your ssh key.  (I experienced this issue when my key was encrypted by my Windows host, but my Docker container couldn't decrypt it.)

You could also always just generate a new key and try that one.